# How to set all content in div html to center position

Tags: html, css

I have problem to centering content in html. How I can centered html content (picture, text,..)? 
How do I align the content (position center) that will be like in 
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLU8e.jpg)?

In html, i have foreach loop that get content from database:

```
<div id="values" >
            <div >
                @foreach (var parameter in @Model.Values)
                {
                    <img class="value" src="@parameter.Image" />
                }
            </div>
            <div >
                @foreach (var parameter in @Model.Values)
                {
                    <p class="value2">@parameter.Name</p>
                }
            </div>
            <div >
                @foreach (var parameter in @Model.Values)
                {
                    <h6 class="value">@parameter.Description</h6>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

And css:

```
#values {
    position: relative;
    align-content:center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    align-items: center;
}

.value {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Lato', calibri;
    bottom: 275px;
    left: 125px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 245px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But I do not get a result like the picture. 
Actually, how can automatically adjust the content as in the picture...

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Two potential problems:

1. You're setting `float: left;` in the class `.value` which is applied to the `img` and the `h6`. Change this to `float: none;` or just remove this line entirely.
2. Setting `left: 125px;` will position the `img` and the `h6` 125px away from their originally rendered position, since you've defined `position: relative;`. This is a very strange thing to do, and most likely won't result in centered images/text. Unless this effect is intentional, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .row {
    background-color: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px  0px;
}
.row-mid {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}
.blocks {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
.blocks img {
    width: 100px;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="row-mid">
        <div class="blocks">
            <img src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/32995f9d7829479a987558e11dde13d0/tumblr_nus0pe0fe11r7m6voo1_1280.png" alt=""/>
            <h4>Some Title</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blocks">
            <img src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/32995f9d7829479a987558e11dde13d0/tumblr_nus0pe0fe11r7m6voo1_1280.png" alt=""/>
            <h4>Some Title</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blocks">
            <img src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/32995f9d7829479a987558e11dde13d0/tumblr_nus0pe0fe11r7m6voo1_1280.png" alt=""/>
            <h4>Some Title</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

please check this http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshpp/477qacwd/

Answer (score 0):

Just put `<center>` before starting the div and `</center>` after closing the div, like this:

```
<center>
    <div id="values" >
            <div >
                @foreach (var parameter in @Model.Values)
                {
                    <img class="value" src="@parameter.Image" />
                }
            </div>
            <div >
                @foreach (var parameter in @Model.Values)
                {
                    <p class="value2">@parameter.Name</p>
                }
            </div>
            <div >
                @foreach (var parameter in @Model.Values)
                {
                    <h6 class="value">@parameter.Description</h6>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
</center>
```

I've also created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWbVxr) and a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yret08zj/) for you.